# Building branches/commits on demand in Travis CI

Tags: travis-ci

I would like to achieve the following setup in Travis CI.

1. Do a build whenever commits are pushed to `dev` or `release` branches only.
2. Disable builds whenever commits are pushed to any other branch apart from `dev` or `release` but build pull requests.
3. If a developer is really interested to know if his commits are good, then he should be able to kick start a build on Travis CI explicitly by choosing a branch/commit.

From reading the documentation on Travis CI and some blog posts, I see that I can achieve "**1.**" and "**2.**"

Does anyone know how to make "**3.**" work?

**Update-1:**
The reason I want scenario "**3.**" is because the developers in our team (or in general any other team) make several commits and push them even before they send out a pull request. Building for every single commit of a private branch even before it goes for a pull request is causing lot of requests to queue up in the Travis CI queue which unnecessarily blocks developers who really care to verify a particular commit to check if everything is good or not before sending out a pull request.

Having the following is just fine for us:

- Build on every commit push to `dev` and `release` branches
- Build on every commit pushed to a pull request

Comment: AFAIK you cannot, because that's the whole premise of CI, isn't it? OTOH, they can fork it and use a modified `.travis.yml` there.

Comment: @набиячлэвэлиь : Probably I wasn't very clear earlier...I have updated the post with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve **1** and **2** by whitelisting the branches you want to see push builds for:

```
branches:
  only:
    - dev
    - release
```

For reference, see https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Whitelisting-or-blacklisting-branches.

You can achieve **3** only if your developers open a PR against one of the whitelisted branches.

I'd personally recommend to open a PR as early as possible (after the first commit), as it makes work in progress visible to everyone who is interested.